# Unterschied zwischen "passen" und "stehen"

Tags: difference

Könnte mir jemand den Unterschied zwischen *stehen* und *passen* erklären. Zum Beispiel:

> Diese Schuhe stehen dir gut.
>   Diese Schuhe passen dir gut.

Comment: Was sagt denn das Wörterbuch?

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/38116

Answer (score 14):

Schuhe, die **passen**, umschließen den Fuß so, wie es sein soll, sind weder zu groß noch zu klein.

Schuhe, die dir **stehen**, werten dich optisch auf. Es ist also ein Kompliment, zu sagen:

> Diese Schuhe stehen dir gut!

Das Gesagte gilt für alle Kleidungsstücke, nicht nur für Schuhe. **Passen** heißt »weder zu groß noch zu klein«, **stehen** hat einen Schönheitsbezug.

Comment: Kleine Korrekturnotwendigkeit: "Diese Schuhe stehen dir gut!" bedeutet, dass Du gut in den Schuhen aussiehst, nicht, dass die Schuhe gut an Dir aussehen, auch wenn beides meist Hand in Hand geht.

Answer (score 0):

Die Antwort Pollitzers ist korrekt. Ich möchte nur eine Anmerkung hinzufügen.

Zumindest bei uns hier in Ostösterreich/Wien verwendet man den Ausdruck "etwas steht dir" nicht so häufig. Stattdessen wird der andere Ausdruck "etwas passt dir" für beide Bedeutungen genutzt.

> Dieses Kleid passt dir gut!

Kann also sowohl bedeuten, dass die Größe des Kleides passt, als auch, dass es gut an dir aussieht.

Comment: ... und außerdem gibt es noch, auch in Deutschland: "Dieses Kleid passt gut zu dir" oder "Dieses Kleid passt gut zu den Stiefeln!" mit der Bedeutung, dass du (oder die Stiefel) und das Kleid sich gut ergänzen. Das ist allerdings nicht so eindeutig positiv, es kann unter Umständen auch böse gemeint sein.