# What is the meaning of "jede Farbe steht ihm"?

Tags: idiom, expression

I stumbled upon this phrase in a text, where someone is praising this guy's qualities, and I'm in doubt whether it means that every color fits him (about clothes) or (in a more figurative manner) that he blends comfortably in every situation. Does anyone know this expression? Thank you very much.

Comment: It's about clothes. I never heard or read this in the meaning of blending in comfortably. Such a figurative meaning would involve the word *Chamäleon* and it's not nice.

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/35110

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression is commonly used in a literal sence, i.e. he can wear every color refering to clothes. Sometimes it is used when refering to haircolor, usually when someone dyes their hair.

Answer (score 1):

Yepp, that means: this person looks always beautiful, regardless of what he is wearing. It's a politeness phrase. Rarely meant seriously.